# Drupal add extra fields to menu

Tags: drupal, twig

I have some issue with drupal 9 and the menu. Basically i want to add some extra fields for menu link, like icon (image or svg upload) and some text for description. I use Simplify menu for the menus.

I already tried with Menu item extras module but i can't print the added fields in twig file.

Someone know how to fix this and get the fields value in twig template? (menu.html.twig)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can print it in  `*.html.twig` file, the below code I rendered the main menu like:

```
{% set items = simplify_menu('main') %}

{{ menu_item.NEW_FIELD }}

 <nav class="nav">
   <ul class="navbar-ul">
     {% for menu_item in items.menu_tree %}
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="{{ menu_item.url }}">{{ menu_item.text }}</a>
       </li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
  </nav>
```